# how to save xml file as CLOB into oracle database WITHOUT SAVING INTO OS in java

Tags: java, xml, oracle, clob

I got the task of digitally sign the XML file which which is residing inside the oracle database table and again insert into database. I am doing it by three steps:

1. Fetch the XML file from database (saved as CLOB).
2. Digitally sign it.
3. Save it into some directory as actualfile.xml.
4. Read that file and save it into database as CLOB.

The problem is that I want to do it wihtout saving into directory folder (Step 3). Here is the code which I am using :

```
 private static void storeSignedDoc(Document doc) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
//    public static FileOutputStream storeSignedDoc(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            trans = transFactory.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Document signedXmlFileDoc = null;
            String destnSignedXmlFilePath = "383_ALLA_200417_001_signed.xml";
            StreamResult streamRes = new StreamResult(new File(destnSignedXmlFilePath));

//            StreamResult streamRes = new StreamResult(fileOutputStream);
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), streamRes);

//            trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new Result(signedXmlFileDoc));
            System.out.println("fileOutputStream : " + fileOutputStream);
            ClobFile cb = new ClobFile();
            cb.insertClob();
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("XML file with attached digital signature generated successfully ...");
//        return fileOutputStream;
    }//storeSignedDoc() ends here
```

while for retrieving and inserting the xml file :

```
public InputStream getByteByClob(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Clob clob = null;
ResultSet rs = cs.connect(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            clob = rs.getClob(1);
        }
InputStream clobStream = clob.getAsciiStream();
return clobStream;
    }

public void insertClob() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException {

String query = "---UPDATE QUERY ----";
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("-- AS REQUIRED --");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        File f = new File("myfile_signed.xml");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);

        pstmt.setCharacterStream(1, fr, (int) f.length());
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(i + " records affected");

        con.close();
    }
}
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem..